# How to use Distributed Data Parallel properly in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I’m relatively new to PyTorch, but I have good experience with Keras & TensorFlow. I’ve followed this [article](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html) to use DDP on my own training script. However, for some reason, I always end up getting:

> process 0 terminated with exit status 1.

I've tried running the same code on multiple GPU platforms (Google Colab, Kaggle, Floyd Hub), but all of them pretty much threw me the same error.

I've also tried disabling the `join=True` option, but then the training process doesn't even start.

DDP related code:

```py
def setup(rank, world_size):
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12355'

    # initialize the process group
    dist.init_process_group("gloo", rank=rank, world_size=world_size)

    # Explicitly setting seed to make sure that models created in two processes
    # start from same random weights and biases.
    torch.manual_seed(42)


def cleanup():
    dist.destroy_process_group()


def run_demo(fn, *args):
    mp.spawn(
        fn,
        args = (args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4]),
        nprocs = 1, # Also tried 2 , but no difference
        join = True
    )
```

And my training code:

```py
def train(model, X, batch_size = 32, epochs = 75, gradient_acc = 0):
    setup(1, 2)
    device = model.get_default_device()
    model = model.to(device, non_blocking = True)
    ddp_model = DDP(model, device_ids = [0]) # Only one GPU

    # ...

    ddp_model.hidden_enc = ddp_model.init_hidden_enc()
    ddp_model.hidden_dec = ddp_model.init_hidden_dec()

    ddp_model.train()

    for ep in range(epochs):
        loss_br = 0; nb_batch_steps = 0
        for step, batch in enumerate( data_loader ):
            batch = batch.to(device, non_blocking = True)
            nb_batch_steps += 1
            loss = ddp_model(batch)
            # ...
    cleanup()
```

Call to training code:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_demo(
        train,
        model, 
        holder[:], # X
        32, 
        75,
        3
    )
```

I want the model to be running on multiple processes using distributed parallel package. Interestingly, sometimes I get `Out of Memory` exception for CUDA when I run it without using DDP. I understand that `spawn.py` terminates all the processes if any of the available processes exist with `status code > 1`, but I can't seem to figure out yet how to avoid this issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to pytorch [DDP tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html),

> Across processes, DDP inserts necessary parameter synchronizations in forward passes and gradient synchronizations in backward passes. It is up to users to map processes to available resources, as long as processes do not share GPU devices.

I think you cannot initialize the model in DDP on one GPU when each process needs to share this GPU device.